# How to differentiate between mousedown and mousedrag

Tags: javascript, frontend, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am performing some actions on onMousedown event. But then they also get executed for drag as drag starts with mouse down.

How can I ensure that actions on mouse-down don't happen for mouse drag?

Note: I am using scalajs-react, though that must not matter.

Comment: Why are you using `mouseDown`? is there a more appropriate event that could be used instead?

Comment: I guess mouseup event is a better fit here.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse drag events trigger an event of [`DragEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DragEvent) type, mouse down triggers only [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent). You can differentiate both, by validating [`dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent/dataTransfer) attribute, which is only present in [`DragEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DragEvent), like this:

```js
function functionTriggeredOnMouseDownAndDrag(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.dataTransfer !== 'undefined') {
        // code for mouse drag
    } else {
        // code for other mouse events
    }
}

element.addEventListener('mousedown', functionTriggeredOnMouseDownAndDrag)
element.addEventListener('mousemove', functionTriggeredOnMouseDownAndDrag)
```